# Convert html view to a image

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I want to convert a html view to a image. This is the div code

```
<html>
<div class="row">
<!--image div -->
<div id="imgspace1" class="container cropit-image-preview1" class="col-md-12" style="border: 1px solid black; height: 250px; position: absolute; top: 10px; right: 10px; left: 10px; background-size: cover;">
convert this div to a image.</div></div>
</html>
```

i want to convert this html view to a image. does anyone know ?

Comment: [wkhtml2pdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/)

Comment: which way you want ?

Comment: If you want to reuse this as an image of a page. you can save this code in a table and then you can insert it where you want to show it later.

Comment: I want if i put a button on this code and when i press it, that div should save as a image on a file. Think if I insert a image to this div and when I press that button, image div should save as a image to my computer.

Comment: please have a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38673843/how-to-convert-html-code-or-data-containing-image-tag-and-some-text-into-image/38675023#38675023

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**`html2canvas`**](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/examples.html) library:

```js
function convertImg() {
  html2canvas(document.querySelector('.row'), {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
      document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    }
  });
}

$('button').click(convertImg);
```

```css
.row > div {
  background: red;
  color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.js"></script>
<button>Convert page as img.</button>
<div class="row" style='height:260px; position:relative; top:10px;'>
  <div id="imgspace1" class="container cropit-image-preview1" class="col-md-12" style="border: 1px solid black; height: 250px; position: absolute; top: 10px; right: 10px; left: 10px; background-size: cover;">
    convert this div to a image.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a library that converts HTML to HTML-Canvas. This Canvas can be saved as an image afterwards. Check out the examples:

http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/